# Java Swing rendering bug on Windows 7 look-and-feel?

Tags: java, swing, windows-7

The knob on vertical JSlider's on my Windows 7 machine (with native look-and-feel) is really, really tiny in both directions. Not just skinny but short as well. [image]

Can anyone confirm this? Should I report it? If so, where? Thanks!

Here is the code for the sample program (in the screen shot):

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.UIManager;


public class SliderTest
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        // Set the look and feel to that of the system
        try
        { UIManager.setLookAndFeel( UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName() ); }
        catch ( Exception e )
        { System.err.println( e ); }


        // Launch the GUI from the event dispatch thread
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable()
        {
            public void run ()
            {
                JFrame window = new JFrame();
                window.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

                JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
                contentPane.add( new JSlider(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL) );
                contentPane.add( new JSlider(SwingConstants.VERTICAL) );

                window.setContentPane( contentPane );
                window.pack();
                window.setLocationRelativeTo( null ); // Center window
                window.setVisible( true );
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it's a bug, but I see the same thing.

Comment: I think it's worth making visible to Sun, er, Oracle ;P  I think I'll post something on bugs.sun.com (I think that's the place to go?).

Comment: Looks normal on Mac OS X 10.5.8 Java 1.6 for all installed L&Fs. Is this an artifact of `FlowLayout`, the default for `JPanel`?

Comment: I tried some variations using BoxLayout and BorderLayout and the issue showed up in all cases.  Seems like the component's UI under the Windows 7 Look-and-Feel.

Comment: @JohnB Did you submit something on bugs.sun.com? What is the bug ID?

Comment: Christopher, I don't think I ever did (I think was waiting for an answer here and forgot). I haven't done Java development in a long time, so if you want to go ahead and submit a bug. Feel free to use the code/graphic above if they still apply to the latest version.

Answer (score 4):

First off, this happens in Windows Vista too. It seems to be the case, that the slider tries to take as little space as possible. If you want a bigger `JSlider` use `JSlider.setPaintTicks`. So you have to add the following:

```
JSlider vertical = new JSlider( SwingConstants.VERTICAL );
vertical.setPaintTicks( true );
contentPane.add( vertical );
```

That should do the trick.